# How can I stop html loading after certain seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got a bunch of HTML to check, and every time I try to load it with driver.get("HTML"), it takes too long time to finish loading. I mean, it already shows what I need within 2 seconds, and then it keeps loading things for about 10 seconds I think.

I think I have searched enough. Here are things I have tried.

1. set_page_load_timeout
   I used

   driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)

   try:
       driver.get("HTML")
   except TimeoutException:
       pass

But I found out that, after it gets TimeOutException, it doesn't reactivate it, so the driver can't load the second HTML and go right into the TimeoutException

2. pageLoadStrategy :

Actually, this would work. But unfortunately, I'm using two drivers. The first driver is the one collecting HTML, and the second one is to load those downloaded HTMLs.

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
normal = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
normal["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"

driver2 = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver78.exe", chrome_options=options2, desired_capabilities=caps)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver78.exe", chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities = normal)
```

The problem I found is that only one "desired_capabilities" which was set last is applied. Which means, driver and driver2 share the last desired_capabilities setting... So if I set driver later, there is no difference for the driver2 and it just load HTML for about 10 seconds. if I set driver2 later, the whole procedure for driver is ruined because it keeps activate things before the page is completely loaded.

So... Would it be better way for my case? Hope I get some help.

Comment: why are you using two drivers? you can create only one driver with set `pageLoadStrategy`  to `"eager"`. and after that, you can get data from HTML.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara Well, actually first driver will be headless and after all this, I'm going to make it exe file with PyInstaller. It will be a massive works of simple repeat with some decision of deciding if the HTML is the one I want or not. That's why I thought it would be much convenient to manuplate exe file only, and then check HTML seperately.

Comment: I can't get your clarification. why are you create two browser instances? describe your problem.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara Well, the work is collecting HTML of people from the people-search sites. So I need to open HTML and check it if there is any wrong about HTML, and if I got the right guy as well. (And actually, I need to compare it with other site so... there is the 3rd browser as well.)

The first browser shows me the list of the guys with a certain name, and when I pick it, it downloads the HTML, and then second one showed me the HTML, and third one showed me cross check
The problem is when I choose a guy and reading it from my downloaded HTML to check up, it takes too long time to load.